# How to remove __NEXT_DATA__ from dom in NextJs?

Tags: next.js, server-side-rendering

Because of **NEXT_DATA** element dom size is getting very high and it is affecting to the performance. Can anyone plz help me to remove **NEXT_DATA** from dom?
I am using full server-side rendering with dynamic routes in next Js.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**TLDR:** If you would(/could) remove the `__NEXT_DATA__` script tag, React wouldn't be able to [hydrate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#hydrate). You either hardcode the data in the page or try to reduce your `pageProps` payload, returned from `getServerSideProps`.

I came upon this issue also recently, where I asked myself, why would there be a need for the **content to be included** in the HTML **2 times**.

1. As the content itself - when your NextJS renders the appropriate HTML and sends it to the client
2. As JSON in `<script>` tag - This is because of the need for *rehydration* on the client side.

#### "Solutions"

- **Returning only necessary data from data-fetching method** - I can recommend reading up on this article  [Reducing HTML payload with NextJS](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/05/reduce-data-sent-client-nextjs/), in which they talk about formatting / aggregating the necessary data and returning only the needed fields.
- **Not using the data-fetching method and hardcoding static content** - The idea behind using *static* data fetching, if not using `revalidate` option, is that the content shouldn't be changing (maybe ever). So in that case, why couldn't we hardcode the data in the page itself. Althought downside of this of course is, having to write it all out manually / download the required content to some JSON / object and then use it in the page like so.

##### Reading

1. Here's a [github link with related discussion in next](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13418#) in which you might be interested.
2. [Blog post about reducing the size of `__NEXT_DATA__`](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2021/05/reduce-data-sent-client-nextjs/) - by [Liran Cohen](https://twitter.com/LaptopCouch).

Comment: Why __NEXT_DATA__ can't be dynamically loaded?

Comment: @FilipeGiusti Since `NEXT_DATA` is added by _NextJS_ you'd probably have to mess with _Next's_ internals.. Otherwise, I don't think it's really possible. 

Also, _Next_ uses this script tag for some of its own data, like whether or not is this page SSG or SSR, etc.., so the page wouldn't have this data at inicialization.

Comment: I'm the author of one of the tools mentioned in the Smashing Magazine article. We've been seeing a lot of size issues with embedded JSON, so now we have an HTML Size Analyzer that lets you inspect the JSON as well: https://www.debugbear.com/html-size-analyzer

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you might not require some of the __NEXT_DATA__ props during client side rendering.

To drop those props, you can mutate the `NextScript.getInlineScriptSource` function in the `_document.tsx` file. Here is an example:

```
// _document.tsx

const nextInlineScriptSource = NextScript.getInlineScriptSource;
NextScript.getInlineScriptSource = (props) => {
  if (props?.__NEXT_DATA__?.foo) {
    props.__NEXT_DATA__.foo = 'bar';
  }
  return nextInlineScriptSource(props);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this to not show `__NEXT_DATA__`:

```
export const config = {
  unstable_runtimeJS: false,
};
```

But all JavaScript functionality will not work in frontend.

Comment: Note that this does not appear to work in the development environment where the HMR features are enabled but your production responses will indeed not have `__NEXT_DATA__`.

Answer (score 0):

If you come across this issue, make sure you don't have any conditional rendering. This is how I solved this issue myself !

Answer (score 0):

As of Next.js version 13, the new answer appears to be Server Components:

> Components in the Server Component module graph are guaranteed to be only rendered on the server.

https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/rendering/server-and-client-components

It's still in beta, but the idea seems to be that if your app only consists of server components, then it can be rendered completely beforehand, with no need for client-side javascript or `__NEXT_DATA__`.

Comment: I tried this without success so far

Answer (score 0):

In Current version can't hide this page props data from view source.

We can encrypt this data using crypto-js library, you can also use other library for encryption and decryption data.

```
// Add two function for encryption and decryption
const secretKey = "your_secret_key"
// Encryption 
function encryptData(data) {
    const ciphertext = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(JSON.stringify(data), secretKey);
    return ciphertext.toString();
  }
    
  
// Decryption 
function decryptData(encryptedData) {
    const bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encryptedData, secretKey);
    const decryptedData = JSON.parse(bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8));
    return decryptedData;
  }


//Add in getServerSideProps     
const pagePropsData = JSON.stringify({
        someData:"Some data",
        otherData : "Other Data"
      });

    const secureData = encryptData(pagePropsData)
      return {
        props: {
          secureData
        }
      }

// add in page component
export default function PageDetail({secureData}) {
  const decryptedData = decryptData(secureData);
  const {someData, otherData} = JSON.parse(decryptedData)
```

Now page props encrypted in view source

Answer (score -1):

To remove the **rehydration** data `regex: <script id="__NEXT_DATA__((.|n)*)script>` from all pages of the static website run the following command after the build has finished:

`find out -name '*.html' | xargs perl -0777 -pi -e 's/<script id="__NEXT_DATA__.*?script>//sg;'`