# how to hide the JSON from the html file?

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am using the `getServerSideProps` in  `next js` . everything is working properly but one issue that I consider is that the `JSON` data is also shown when I click the `open page source`  .The code is

```
import { getAllPost } from '../helper/post'

export default function Home(props) {

  return (
    <div >
      <Head>

        <title>YourGuide &#8211; Real Essence Of Your City</title>
        <meta name="description" content="Generated by create next app" />
        <a rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
        <link
          href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
          rel="stylesheet"
          integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
          crossorigin="anonymous"
        />


      </Head>
      <LandingPage />
      <TopCites post={props.post}/>
    </div>
  )
}
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {

  const post = await getAllPost();
  return {
    props: { post:post }, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

I used the props data in component of `TopCities`  The code of the component is

```
export default function TopCites(props) {

    const router = useRouter();
    const top = [
        {
            city: "Lahore",
            img: lahore
        },
        {

            city: "Rawalpindi",
            img: rawalpindi
        },
        {
            city: "Karachi",
            img: karachi
        },
        {
            city: "Gilgit City",
            img: gilgit
        }
    ]
    return (
        <>
            <div className=" my-4">
                <div className="row  ">
                    <div className="col-lg-5 col-md-5   col-sm-12   text-dark">
                        <h2 >Top Cities</h2>
                        <hr />
                        <div className="row   ">
                            {
                                top.map(city => {
                                    return <div key={city.city} className="col-6  px-2">
                                        <div className=' removeDecor' onClick={() => { router.push(`/city/${city.city}`) }} role="button" >
                                            <Image src={city.img} className={style.postImg }   alt={lahore} />
                                            <h5 className='centerText'>{city.city} </h5>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                })
                            }

                            <hr />
                        </div>

                    </div>

                    <div className= {`col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-sm-12 container ${style.overflowData} text-dark `}>
                        {
                            props.post.length > 0 ? <h3>Most Recent Post</h3> : <div>
                                <h1>We are unable to show the articls now</h1>
                                <Image src={lahore} alt="lahore" width={500} height={300} />
                            </div>}
                        {
                            props.post.length > 0 ? props.post.map(post => {
                                return <Post key={post.postId} post={post} />
                            }) : ""
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Everything is working properly but the issue is that the `JSON` is shown in the `view page source` .  I am unable to solve this problem. I want to hide the `JSON` data from the file. kindly tell me how to solve this problem.

Comment: If you mean the data visible in the `__NEXT_DATA__` script, then it's not possible to hide that. Next.js hydration process on the client-side needs that data to work when using SSR. See https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/13418 and [How to remove __NEXT_DATA__ from dom in NextJs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396462/how-to-remove-next-data-from-dom-in-nextjs).