# Why JSON data is sent inside HTML nextjs SSG

Tags: html, next.js, static-site-generation

I know that in the case of page loading the whole html document is being sent and in case of client side routing the json file and js chunk are being sent instead.

But I don't know why in the first case which html file has filled with data, why should it contain json data also. Is it necessary? I mean we don't need those anymore because we have html file with data.

e.g:

```
<div id="__next">
  <div>
    <h1>Leanne Graham</h1><span>Sincere@april.biz</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Ervin Howell</h1><span>Shanna@melissa.tv</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Clementine Bauch</h1><span>Nathan@yesenia.net</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Patricia Lebsack</h1><span>Julianne.OConner@kory.org</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Chelsey Dietrich</h1><span>Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Mrs. Dennis Schulist</h1><span>Karley_Dach@jasper.info</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Kurtis Weissnat</h1><span>Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Nicholas Runolfsdottir V</h1><span>Sherwood@rosamond.me</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Glenna Reichert</h1><span>Chaim_McDermott@dana.io</span>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1>Clementina DuBuque</h1><span>Rey.Padberg@karina.biz</span>
  </div>
</div>
<script id="__NEXT_DATA__"
        type="application/json">{"props":{"pageProps":{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Leanne Graham","username":"Bret","email":"Sincere@april.biz","address":{"street":"Kulas Light","suite":"Apt. 556","city":"Gwenborough","zipcode":"92998-3874","geo":{"lat":"-37.3159","lng":"81.1496"}},"phone":"1-770-736-8031 x56442","website":"hildegard.org","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Crona","catchPhrase":"Multi-layered client-server neural-net","bs":"harness real-time e-markets"}},{"id":2,"name":"Ervin Howell","username":"Antonette","email":"Shanna@melissa.tv","address":{"street":"Victor Plains","suite":"Suite 879","city":"Wisokyburgh","zipcode":"90566-7771","geo":{"lat":"-43.9509","lng":"-34.4618"}},"phone":"010-692-6593 x09125","website":"anastasia.net","company":{"name":"Deckow-Crist","catchPhrase":"Proactive didactic contingency","bs":"synergize scalable supply-chains"}},{"id":3,"name":"Clementine Bauch","username":"Samantha","email":"Nathan@yesenia.net","address":{"street":"Douglas Extension","suite":"Suite 847","city":"McKenziehaven","zipcode":"59590-4157","geo":{"lat":"-68.6102","lng":"-47.0653"}},"phone":"1-463-123-4447","website":"ramiro.info","company":{"name":"Romaguera-Jacobson","catchPhrase":"Face to face bifurcated interface","bs":"e-enable strategic applications"}},{"id":4,"name":"Patricia Lebsack","username":"Karianne","email":"Julianne.OConner@kory.org","address":{"street":"Hoeger Mall","suite":"Apt. 692","city":"South Elvis","zipcode":"53919-4257","geo":{"lat":"29.4572","lng":"-164.2990"}},"phone":"493-170-9623 x156","website":"kale.biz","company":{"name":"Robel-Corkery","catchPhrase":"Multi-tiered zero tolerance productivity","bs":"transition cutting-edge web services"}},{"id":5,"name":"Chelsey Dietrich","username":"Kamren","email":"Lucio_Hettinger@annie.ca","address":{"street":"Skiles Walks","suite":"Suite 351","city":"Roscoeview","zipcode":"33263","geo":{"lat":"-31.8129","lng":"62.5342"}},"phone":"(254)954-1289","website":"demarco.info","company":{"name":"Keebler LLC","catchPhrase":"User-centric fault-tolerant solution","bs":"revolutionize end-to-end systems"}},{"id":6,"name":"Mrs. Dennis Schulist","username":"Leopoldo_Corkery","email":"Karley_Dach@jasper.info","address":{"street":"Norberto Crossing","suite":"Apt. 950","city":"South Christy","zipcode":"23505-1337","geo":{"lat":"-71.4197","lng":"71.7478"}},"phone":"1-477-935-8478 x6430","website":"ola.org","company":{"name":"Considine-Lockman","catchPhrase":"Synchronised bottom-line interface","bs":"e-enable innovative applications"}},{"id":7,"name":"Kurtis Weissnat","username":"Elwyn.Skiles","email":"Telly.Hoeger@billy.biz","address":{"street":"Rex Trail","suite":"Suite 280","city":"Howemouth","zipcode":"58804-1099","geo":{"lat":"24.8918","lng":"21.8984"}},"phone":"210.067.6132","website":"elvis.io","company":{"name":"Johns Group","catchPhrase":"Configurable multimedia task-force","bs":"generate enterprise e-tailers"}},{"id":8,"name":"Nicholas Runolfsdottir V","username":"Maxime_Nienow","email":"Sherwood@rosamond.me","address":{"street":"Ellsworth Summit","suite":"Suite 729","city":"Aliyaview","zipcode":"45169","geo":{"lat":"-14.3990","lng":"-120.7677"}},"phone":"586.493.6943 x140","website":"jacynthe.com","company":{"name":"Abernathy Group","catchPhrase":"Implemented secondary concept","bs":"e-enable extensible e-tailers"}},{"id":9,"name":"Glenna Reichert","username":"Delphine","email":"Chaim_McDermott@dana.io","address":{"street":"Dayna Park","suite":"Suite 449","city":"Bartholomebury","zipcode":"76495-3109","geo":{"lat":"24.6463","lng":"-168.8889"}},"phone":"(775)976-6794 x41206","website":"conrad.com","company":{"name":"Yost and Sons","catchPhrase":"Switchable contextually-based project","bs":"aggregate real-time technologies"}},{"id":10,"name":"Clementina DuBuque","username":"Moriah.Stanton","email":"Rey.Padberg@karina.biz","address":{"street":"Kattie Turnpike","suite":"Suite 198","city":"Lebsackbury","zipcode":"31428-2261","geo":{"lat":"-38.2386","lng":"57.2232"}},"phone":"024-648-3804","website":"ambrose.net","company":{"name":"Hoeger LLC","catchPhrase":"Centralized empowering task-force","bs":"target end-to-end models"}}]},"__N_SSG":true},"page":"/users","query":{},"buildId":"_BVHaFbNlMSfT1OwVq3vf","isFallback":false,"gsp":true,"scriptLoader":[]}</script>
```

You see last line which is json script and it's a copy of data above it

Answer (score 1):

This happens because React needs to get the data from somewhere when hydrating the page initially during the server side rendering. After initial render, the `__NEXT_DATA__` is picked up from DOM if there is a rehydration, saving on server side renders and reducing calls

Theres some info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69396462/how-to-remove-next-data-from-dom-in-nextjs) which clarifies how to remove it if you so wish, but without it any javascript that relies on the props will fail to run or rehydrate.

Comment: if I see request for js and json files instead of an HTML file does it mean that the page has client side routing and not server side routing?
I have a SSG page but wondering why I see request for js and json file instead of request for the html for the page